# jQuery load tracking pixel and after that redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I have a tracking pixel and want to load it with jquery. After the successful loading I want to make a redirect to one url.

Now I have this code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">   
    document.write("<img src=\'PIXEL_TRACKING_URL\' width=\"1\" height=\"1\" \'> ");

    function redirect(){
       window.location.replace(URL);
    }

    setTimeout(redirect, 2500);
</script>
```

The problem is, when the tracking pixel tooks more then 2,5 seconds, then there is the redirect happen and I can not track the redirect.

Some help please, so I only redirect, when the image is loadet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'PIXEL_TRACKING_URL';
if (image.addEventListener) {
  image.addEventListener('load', function() {
    window.location.replace(URL);
  });
} else {
  // it's IE!
  image.attachEvent('onload', function() {
    window.location.replace(URL);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made this with jQuery in this form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var image = $("IMAGE");
   $("body").append(image);  
    image.load(function() {                 
      setTimeout(redirect, 1000);
    });
});

function redirect(){
   window.location.replace("URL");
}
```